# What's the meaning of 'characters' in 'weaknesses in the characters of emperors and generals'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As well as making sense of events through narratives, historians in the ancient world established the tradition of history as a source of moral lessons and reflections. The history writing of Livy or Tacitus, for instance, was in part designed to examine the behavior of heroes and villains, meditating on the strengths and weaknesses in the **characters** of emperors and generals, providing exemplars for the virtuous to imitate or avoid. This continues to be one of the functions of history. French chronicler Jean Froissart said he had written his accounts of chivalrous knights fighting in the Hundred Years’ War “so that brave men should be inspired thereby to follow such examples.” Today, historical studies of Lincoln, Churchill, Gandhi, or Martin Luther King, Jr. perform the same function.
>
> The History Book: Big Ideas Simply Explained, 2016

Does the word 'character' mean traits of a person or people that appear on a stage or in a novel?

Comment: Which do **you** suppose it means? Why?

Comment: Because it is confusing.

Comment: The passage is about writing **history**, which is about real people  Does that help?

Comment: My *Why?* was, *And why do you suppose that meaning?* Here on ELL, posting bare questions without indication of one’s own thoughts and efforts to find answers is considered bad form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this appearance, followed immediately by "of emperors and generals", "characters" **refers to the traits or qualities** of those emperors and generals.

If the word appeared without "of emperors and generals", it might mean, metaphorically, an individual who appears in a book or play, for example,
"the strength or weaknesses of the characters who have appeared on the stage of world history".